# Django signal doesn't execute a function from my consumer

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, django-signals, consumer

I have a problem regarding my consumer. or Django signal? I wasn't able to send a message from my group in the web socket by using my Django signal to execute the function from my consumer.

I have here a Django signal code, which executes/tracks my model if being updated and it executes correctly:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def check_got_data_update_to_true(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.got_data:
        print(f"from django signals: {instance.id}")
        print(f"from django signals: {instance.company_website}")
        message = f"from django signals: {instance.id}"
        send_data_to_consumers(message)


def send_data_to_consumers(message):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    try:
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            "test",
            {
                "type": "handle_signal_message",
                "message": message,
            },
        )
        print("Group message sent successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending group message: {str(e)}")
```

now when there is an update from my model, my Django signals execute properly and output the message of Group message sent successfully in logs.

Now here, I have a consumer that my Django signals calling the function of `handle_signal_message` and I don't know why this doesn't execute. Since when i put a print inside the function, it doesn't print.
Here is the full code of my consumer:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import (
    AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer,
    AsyncWebsocketConsumer,
    JsonWebsocketConsumer,
)
import json


class TestConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add("test", self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
        print("Connected!")

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("Disconnected!")
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("test", self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(data)
        await self.events_handler[data["event"]](self, data)

    async def handle_signal_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        print(f"Received message in handle_signal_message: {message}")
        await self.send_json({"message_from_signal": message})

    ### client events here ###

    async def event_received_message(self, data):
        msg = data["data"]
        print(msg)

    ### client end of events ###

    ### events handler ###
    events_handler = {"EVENT_MESSAGE_RECEIVE": event_received_message}

    ### end of events handler ###
```

I'm using a postman to test the connection and it works fine. Actually, my server receives messages from my Postman client connecting in the ws. My problem is that in Django signals don't execute my consumer function.

Comment: I doubt whether you able to call send_data_to_consumers from signal, since its expect to work in synchronous way, you can search for how to call an async task from signals.

Comment: @Jisson hi. i think handle_signal_message is not executing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74742694/django-signals-calling-asynchronous-task-without-celery

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/#sync-to-async

Comment: still it doesnt execute . Btw, my function is located from the other app.
I have a directory apps->users->signal and the other apps->websocket->consumers

Comment: first test your signal for a  test  synchronous   function ( eg: update a value in db)

Comment: signal working good. The problem is the consumer. it doesn't execute the function in type

Comment: is it happening in django development server, or did you hosted it some thing like in daphne, You can test your consumer code using django shell, and make sure its working.

Comment: @Jisson i've already deployed it in uvicorn test server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255470/discussion-between-jisson-and-jc-john).